# Limited Characters on a line

Tags: php

I am designing a small application which shoots out status-like tweets from users at the five latest ones. To keep it a small application, I need for it to accept only so many characters on a line and the drop a line just below it. So for example:

> Noah: The best thing about Stackoverflow
>
> is that it is full of amazing programmers.

Something along the lines of something like that above. Can you help me with the code below :

```
  echo "<div style='position:relative;top:-20px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;'>";
  echo "<p> $first_name: $body. </p>"; 
  if (strlen($body <= 100)) {
      echo "\n";
  }
  echo "</div>";                                            
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

[wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) will do that for you

```
string wordwrap ( string $str [, int $width = 75 [, string $break = "\n" [, bool $cut = false ]]] )
```

Example:

```
$text = "A very long woooooooooooord.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, "\n", true);

echo "$newtext\n";

A very
long
wooooooo
ooooord.
```